# ProgressBar update from within Handler

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a syncing service that I want a progress bar for, because it takes >1 minute to sync all the data and I don't want to use indeterminate progress. I have a Handler for the syncing functions and am referencing and correctly updating the progressBar's progress but the UI does not update.

```
  Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                 //Sync calls
                     updateProgress(getContext());
                }
 };
 public static void updateProgress(Context c){
    layout = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    progress_view = layout.inflate(R.layout.sync_dialog, null);

    mProgressStatus += mProgressStep;
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) progress_view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

    mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
}
```

I have tried using an ASynchTask class with no success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you inflating the view in your updateProgress method? And have you tried updating it on the UI thread using runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { } });

Answer (score 2):

Let this my example of right use of `Handler`.

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            bar.incrementProgressBy(5);
            if (bar.getProgress() == 100) {
                bar.setProgress(0);
                Toast.makeText(ThreadsDemoActivity.this, "Progress is finished.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

Then you have to create `Thread`(now it do only some simulation or work)

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bar.setProgress(0);
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20 && isRunning; i++) {
                        Thread.sleep(300);
                        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                    }
                }
                catch (Throwable t) {

                }
            }
        });
        isRunning = true;
        backgroundThread.start();
    }

public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isRunning = false;
    }
```

Also in `onCreate` method you have to declare and initialise `progressBar`

```
bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progBar)
```

So this is good but not always. More complex approach offers `AsyncTask`. It's very complex and strong tool and when i would recommend to you something so clearly it's `AnyncTask`. It's generic type and has one method named `doInBackground()` that are using for long-time tasks and trasfers your task to background. There is one rule that you cannot update `UI` from background thread. You cannot but `AsyncTask` offers `onProgressUpdate()` method that are using for updating `UI`. But enough, if you want, have look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Regards

Answer (score 1):

you should use `Thread` **or** [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that,And only handler update progressBar meanwhile you sync all the data.

[See this Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-asynctask-example.html) and put your sync code in `doInBackground method`