# View's Visibility change don't work well programatically

Tags: android, android-view, visibility

I am trying to add a progressBar in my activity. In layout XML file i set android:visibility="gone" for both progressBar and textView which shows progress level. I'd like to press a button and start a process with progressBar and textview visibility="visible" and then hide them again after process ends.

This is my button code.[image]

The problem is that when I press discover button, nothing is shown !!!
When I remove the two lines before Log.e("visibilty","GONE"), the Views become visible only after process ends. It seems like the setVisibility instructions are executed after While Loop which is so weird.

[image]

Any solution guys ?

Comment: Please don't post your code in image form. Always copy it into the question itself. If you're worried about keeping your code formatted, look at StackOverflow's Markdown rules [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to modify the UI with delays in the main UI thread. This is not going to work as expected. You can use an `AsyncTask` for this that will update the view and hide it at the end.

```
private class Sample extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do in background, NO UI HERE
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                this.publishProgress(); //Call onProgressUpdate
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.interrupted();
            }
        }
        return "Finished!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //After it's completed, touch UI here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       //Before it starts, touch UI here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        //Update text here, touch UI here
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't go that far. A Handler should be all OP needs.

Comment: agree for his particular case it may be a bit overkill

Comment: Thanks. it works pretty good, i did it like this :
discover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Sample task = new Sample();
                        task.onPreExecute();
                        task.doInBackground();
                    }
                });

But it does not handle the method onPostExecute(). In consequence the progress bar and textView remain visible after process ends. 
Any clue to fix that issue ?

Comment: You don't call the methods directly like that, you'd call `execute` on the task

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to run some code after a delay, you can use a Handler+Runnable instead of sleeping the main thread.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable hideRunnable = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Your visibility logic
  }
};  
handler.postDelayed(hideRunnable, 190); // 190 milliseconds
```

There is some discussion about [Updating a ProgressBar with a Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919508/progressbar-update-from-within-handler). If you do need some progress-tracking, AsyncTask does have that built-in.

Comment: Thank you ! I have already tried this solution, but after a little bit time of process it lauches me a fatal error saying : android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: that's the reason why I renounced the handler/Runnable solution and switched to main thread with classic While loop and thread.sleep instruction.

Comment: Oh, then you needed an additional `runOnUiThread` inside the Runnable. In any case, definitely don't sleep the main thread.